# Count occurrences of a string in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, string

I have an Excel file containing a piece of HTML code in a cell:

`<li>item 1</li><li>item 2</li><li>item 3</li>`

Now I want to count the occurrences of the string "`<li>`" in the cell. I searched on the web and used the fairly popular formula:

> `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"<li>",""))`

The result of which I am hoping for should obviously be **`3`** but for some unknown reason, it gives **`12`**:

[image: Count string occurrences error]

How do I get it to work as intended?

Comment: You are replacing `<li>` with a null string, so you lose four characters for each occurrence. Either divide the result by 4 or substitute a string of length 3, eg `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"<li>","+++"))`.

Comment: If you haven't realized yet, you're getting `12` because you are (successfully) counting the total characters that exist when `<li>` is found. 3 occurrences * 4 characters per occurrence. When you replace `<li>` it's replacing four characters...three times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is giving 12, as it counts `<li>` as a 4, as that is its length, so to fix this simply use:

`=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"<li>",""))/4`

Or i prefer to use `SUMPRODUCT` :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"<li>","")))/4
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to divide by the length of the substituted string:

```
=(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"<li>","")))/4
```